# Q - executing a series of promises and defining dependencies between them in a DAG

Tags: javascript, graph, graph-theory, method-chaining, q

I would like to process a series of data, where the output of each may be used as inputs into the others.

For example:

```
    var batch = [
        {"id":"a1","depends":[],"data":{"some":"data a1"}},
        {"id":"b1","depends":["a1"],"data":{"some":"data b1"}},
        {"id":"b2","depends":["a1"],"data":{"some":"data b2"}},
        {"id":"c1","depends":["b1","b2"],"data":{"some":"data c1"}},
        {"id":"x1","depends":[],"data":{"some":"data x1"}},
    ];
```

This means that once `a1` is complete, its output will be sent to both `b1` and `b2`;
and when these complete, both of their output will be sent to `c1` (only upon both of their completion.
`x1` may execute in parallel with all of `a1`, `b1`, `b2`, and `c1`;
and `b1` may execute in parallel with `b2`, as no `depends` between them are defined.

Upon completion of `c1` and `x1`, and therefore the completion of all 5 of them, the output of all five should be returned.

We will assume that no circular dependencies are defined, and thus is a directed acyclic graph (DAG)

I would like to know how to implement this using [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference), because:

- All the processing of the data will be asynchronous, and thus I will need to use either callbacks, or deferreds and promises;
  and I prefer the latter
- Promises can double up as a convenient way to define the edges in the graph

However, I have not been able to take this past the conceptual stage

```
var doPromises = {};

var doData = function(data, dependsResultsHash, callback) {
  //Not real processing, simply echoes input after a delay for async simulation purposes
  var out = {
    echo: {
      data: data,
      dependsResultsHash: dependsResultsHash
    }
  };
  setTimeout(function() {
    callback(out);
  }, 1000);
};

var doLine = function(id, depIds, data) {
  var deferred = Q.defer;
  var dependsPromises = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < depIds.length; ++i) {
    var depId = depIds[i];
    dependPromise = doPromises[depId];
    dependsPromises.push(dependPromise);
  }
  Q.all(dependsPromises).then(function(dependsResults) {
    var dependsResultsHash = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < depIds.length; ++i) {
      var depId = depIds[i];
      var depResult = dependsResults[i];
      dependsResultsHash[depId] = depResult;
    }
    doData(data, dependsResultsHash, function(result) {
      deferred.resolve(result);
    });
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}

var doBatch = function(batch) {
  var linePromises = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < batch.length; ++i) {
    var line = batch[i];
    var linePromise = doLine(line.id, line.depends, line.data);
    linePromises.push(linePromise);
    doPromises[line.id] = linePromise;
  }
  Q.all(linePromises).then(function(lineResults) {
    console.log(lineResults);
    deferred.resolve(lineResults);
  });
};

doBatch(batch);
```

(Note that this code is untested and I do not expect it to work, just to illustrate the points necessary for my question.)

I would like to know:

- Am I doing this right? Am I completely missing the point  with the `Q` library. or with deferreds and promises?
- My main concern is with the `doData` function:

  ```
  -- Is the way that I have selected the promises of the lines depended upon from the global list of promises `doPromises` ok?
  -- Is the way that I have obtained the results of the lines depended upon, and inpterpreted that OK?
  ```
- With the `doBatch` function:

  ```
  -- I have a local array for `linePromises` and an external hash for `doPromises`, and I feel that these should be combined. How can I do this correctly?
  ```
- General

  ```
  -- The code above presently assumes that all `deferred`s will eventually keep their `promise`s. What if they fail or throw an exception; how do I make my code more robust in handling this?
  -- I have used a closure allow acces to `doPromises` in both `doBatch` and `doLine`, and it seems a little odd here, is there a better way to do this?
  ```

Comment: Hey bguiz, looks like you have already got a working solution - almost! Replace `Q.defer` with `Q.defer()` in the first statement of your `doLine` function, and it appears that the `dependsResultsHash` from each of the `depends` gets passed into the lines that ask for them, as expected. Very interesting.

Comment: I'll also add, that I'm still wrapping my head around your code, so I'd probably best be leaving the answers to your specific questions to other SO users!

Comment: @bojangle thanks for the input - I ran my code and got an array of `null`s, and thought I had missed out on something major - didn't think it was simple oversight like that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a library that does this:

[qryq](https://github.com/bguiz/qryq) is a NodeJs library that allows one to express a series of queries and define dependencies between them either in parallel, in sequence, or in a directed acyclic graph.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently made a module called [dagmise](https://github.com/spelufo/dagmise) that I am planning on using to make a build system that uses promises as tasks. I ended up making the nodes of the graph functions that return promises. When a node is visited the function at it is evaluated and the returned promised takes its place as the node's value. So even if a node is visited multiple times, the function is only executed once.

I started with the idea that the promises should be the edges, but now I think it is simpler to have them at the nodes. Otherwise you really end up having two kinds of objects in your graphs (nodes/states and edges/promises), which complicates things a bit.

Comment: Well, that sounds like the edges are functions that yield promises (transitions), and nodes are promises (states).

Comment: I thought of that, but I got confused about states and the base cases: those nodes that have no dependencies might need incoming edges/promises, and needed to be handled specially.

Comment: Of course you could do it in many ways, I just chose what I thought resulted in the simplest and more useful model.

Answer (score 1):

I just implemented my own library for this: [promise-dag](https://github.com/vvvvalvalval/promise-dag).

I was not satisfied with the mentioned alternatives (`dagmise`, `qryq`) for the following reasons:

- They impose a concrete Promise implementation. `promise-dag` is compatible with any Promise implementation, without any code dependency.
- They provide a fluent API (chaining methods). I prefer a data-oriented API, which is more programmable and transparent, making it easy to combine computation graphs using ordinary data-structure functions (`_.extend()`, `_.pick()`, ...), as well as add custom instrumentation (profiling / tracing / logging / etc.).